# Something wrong with my heroku deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, express, heroku

```
`NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client &&  npm run build --prefix client`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 254
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the walking-bucket@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
```

This is the error I get when I try to deploy my express/React app to heroku, any ideas what is going wrong?

edit: package.json with build script:

```js
{
  "name": "walking-bucket",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "basketball shot journal log",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client &&  npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.14",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your `build` command look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specific Heroku deployment failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53689411/specific-heroku-deployment-failure)

Comment: @AnonymousSB edited post!

Comment: @slawomirwozniak I updated my original post with the package.json

Comment: You call npm run build from your heroku-postbuild script, but you don’t actually have a build script, that seems like an issue.

Comment: @AnonymousSB Definitely seems possible! What would you suggest for a build script? `"build": server.js"` ?

Comment: @AnonymousSB I was able to fix my deployment with the build script `"build": "react-scripts build"` Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You’re welcome, glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my solution with the build command

`"build": "react-scripts build"`

from the create-react-app package.json