# Heroku deployment issue package.json

Tags: heroku, deployment, package.json

I am attempting to deploy my heroku app using GIT Heroku. I only updated a file. The application deployed without any issue in Oct 2018 when it was built. Below is the error message and package.JSON file. Apparently line 15 of my package.JSON file is causing the error. Is this line of code outdated ?

```
15: "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION-false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

Error:

```
± git push heroku master                                                
Counting objects: 45, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (45/45), done.
Writing objects: 100% (45/45), 5.34 KiB | 1.78 MiB/s, done.
Total 45 (delta 35), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 15, column 3
remote:  !     Unable to parse package.json
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to project.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/project.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/project.git
```

Server Package.JSON

```
{
  "name": "reactexpress",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "boilerplate for React, Express, Mongo",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.1.1",
    "npm": "5.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION-false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.3.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.17",
    "sendgrid": "^5.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
  }
}
```

Client Package.JSON

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-modal": "^3.6.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build-js": "react-scripts build",
    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried if this command works locally? `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION-false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`

Comment: I think you cant use env vars in package.json. NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION. Because of this I think you got the parsing error

Comment: Buildpackage set to node?

Comment: Isnt there a `build` command missing in the package.json? Maybe heroku does not know what to do with your app.

Comment: Procfile includes?

Comment: @SimonFranzen after checking the command again locally it isn't working. I came across this stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53679374/ something-wrong-with-my-heroku-deployment about the build command you mentioned, but the poster doesn't specify where to apply the build command. Should I place the command within the NPM_CONFIG_PROD.. command or on a separate line?

Comment: @SimonFranzen I forgot I'm using a "client" package.JSON file that has the build command. I've included it above.

Comment: Hey, I am a bit confused now. So you trying to deploy a react app AND a node server in the same app on heroku? I think a better approach is to deploy the server in a separated app. For this you can use the npm buildpack for heroku. The other app is your client, a create-react app. So for this app there is also a heroku buildpack. Try our fork -> https://github.com/zauberware/create-react-app-buildpack

Comment: Env vars like NPM_CONFIG_PROD you can set directly in heroku environment variables. Then you dont't have to include this in the scripts

Comment: @SimonFranzen I watched a video on youtube that did a poor job of explaining why there was a need for two package.json files one using react build (client) and the other using node (server). I have since learn how to create cleaner package.json file which fixed this issue. I also needed to delete the package-lock.json file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: hey @user3574939, I am happy you solved your issue. Keep on coding :)